# Why is there a difference between a for-loop optimization and an optimization via a personalized .fit() method for a keras.Model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, keras-layer, model-fitting

I have been trying to create a keras.Model which can fit a Generalized Pareto Distribution (GPD) based on either samples of a GPD or its quantiles. The fit is done by minimizing the difference between the observation and the quantiles of the estimated GPD.

#### Imports

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import tensorflow_probability as tfp
```

## The GPD layer

I created a basic GPD layer by subclassing `keras.layers.Layer` and by keeping the parameters outside of the layer as recommanded for better performances. I am also using the GPD implemented in `tensorflow_probability.distributions.GeneralizedPareto` ([see doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/api_docs/python/tfp/distributions/GeneralizedPareto)). The two parameters of the GPD are `gamma` and `sigma`.

```
class GPD_layer(keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self):
        super(GPD_layer, self).__init__()
    def call(self, gamma,sigma,num):
        pareto = tfp.distributions.GeneralizedPareto(
            loc=0.0,
            scale=sigma,
            concentration=gamma
            )
        return pareto.quantile(tf.cast(tf.range(start=1/(num+1),limit=1.0,delta=1/(num+1),dtype=tf.float64),dtype=tf.float32))
```

## The GPD model

I created a `keras.Model` subclass to have a proper model and to be able to train it like a regular keras.Model. Following the [guide](https://keras.io/guides/customizing_what_happens_in_fit/) provided by the Keras team. I made the following subclass :

```
class GPD_model(keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(GPD_model, self).__init__()
        self.gpd_layer = GPD_layer()
        self.gamma = tf.Variable(
            initial_value=tf.random_normal_initializer(mean=0.2)(shape=(1,),dtype="float32"),
            trainable=True,
            name="gamma")
        self.sigma = tf.Variable(
            initial_value=tf.random_normal_initializer(mean=1.0)(shape=(1,),dtype="float32"),
            trainable=True,
            name="sigma")
        
    def call(self, num, training=None, *args, **kwargs):
        if training:
            return self.gpd_layer(gamma=self.gamma,sigma=self.sigma, num=num)
        return self.gpd_layer(gamma=self.gamma, sigma=self.sigma, num=num)
    
    def train_step(self,data):
        num = data.shape[0]
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            X_gpd = self(num = num,training=True)
            loss = tf.norm(data-X_gpd,ord=1)
        gradients = tape.gradient(loss, [self.sigma, self.gamma])

        self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, [self.sigma, self.gamma]))
        return {"loss":loss}
```

### Training the model

```
N=1000
gamma_th = 0.4
sigma_th = 2.0

pareto = tfp.distributions.GeneralizedPareto(loc=0,scale=sigma_th,concentration=gamma_th)
X_train = pareto.quantile(tf.cast(tf.range(start=1/(N+1),limit=1.0,delta=1/(N+1),dtype=tf.float64),dtype=tf.float32))

model = GPD_model()
model.compile(
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=1e-2),
    loss="mae",
    run_eagerly=True
    )
history = model.fit(X_train, epochs=200, batch_size=X_train.shape[0])
```

This training leads to a value of gamma that becomes negative and that seems to diverge slowly and to the following effect on the loss :
[image: Evolution of personalized fit]

### Creating an other method

This is a method of the class `GPD_model` which is similar to an external training loop.

```
def manual_fit(self,data, epochs):
        history = {"loss":[],"sigma":[],"gamma":[]}
        num = data.shape[0]
        for step in range(epochs):
            with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
                Y = self(num = num)
                loss = tf.norm(data-Y,ord=1)

            gradients = tape.gradient(loss, [self.sigma,self.gamma])
            self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, [self.sigma, self.gamma]))

            history["loss"].append(loss)
            history["sigma"].append(tf.constant(self.sigma))
            history["gamma"].append(tf.constant(gamma))
            print("\n",str(step+1)+"/"+str(epochs))
            print([f"{k}: {history[k][-1]}" for k in history.keys()])
        return history
```

This method leads to the expected behavior for the loss, gamma and sigma.

[image: Evolution of outter loop]

*Note that the two optimization methods were performed with the same number of epochs, the same learning rate and the same optimizer. The oscillations at the end are due to the fact that the learning rate is not the best one.*

## Questions

- Why is there such a different behavior between the two methods?
- Does the `train_step` do something differents than the loops inside `.manual_fit()`?
- What is causing this ? Is it an issue related to the computation of the gradient? The fact that I'm using a `tensorflow_probability.distributions.Distribution`? Is it a difference of in the gradient descent method inside `.fit()` that I don't know?

Comment: You have a typo in your `manual_fit` function, and the `optimizer` variable is not declared. in  Can you fix those errors?

Comment: Thank you for the remarks, I hadn't noticed. Everything should be ok now

Comment: `fit` shuffle by default. You might want to turn that behaviour off (set `shuffle=False` in the call to `fit`).